# Stack management in assembly code

Tags: assembly, stack, 32-bit

I am noob in assembly language and I am trying to understand an assembly code. All seems clear to me except a few operations and specifically these on the stack pointer register (`r1`).

Here is the code:

```
#define A           r2
#define B           r3
#define R           r6


.section .text, "ax"
.global u32mul16

u32mul16:
    ; R = AxB :
    ;       A <= input  r2 (16bits expected)
    ;       B <= input  r3 (16bits expected)
    ;       R <= output r6 (32bits)

    ; stack update and save
    sub     r1, #0x10
    stq     r4, [r1]

    ; multiplication computation
             ...
    ; after computation

    ; prepare the 'return' value
    mov     r2, R

    ldq     r4, [r1]
    add     r1, #0x10

    jmp     [r15]
```

Not that all registers (`r0`,...,`r15`) are 32-bit registers.

My question is the following: why the operations

```
sub r1, #0x10
stq r4, [r1]
```

at the beginning and

```
ldq r4, [r1]
add r1,#0x10
```

at the end are needed? I don't understand what it does.

Also, is there any reason to put the result in the register `r2`?

Comment: Which architecture is this? Wavescalar? You'll have to find out what the procedure call standard for that architecture is.

Comment: It is an Harvard architecture with RISC-like load/store instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said, you have to find out what the procedure call standard for that architecture is.

The `sub` allocates space from the stack, which is needed for storing `r4` and possibly also used for local variables in the computation code that is omitted. Presumably `r4` is also modified in that block of code, and the calling convention may designate that as a callee-saved register, hence its value must be preserved. If you don't need locals and you don't modify `r4`, then you most probably do not need those instructions.

Similarly, the calling convention specifies which register to use for passing and returning arguments.